# zsh: ${(f)...} doesn't split when used with assignment

Tags: split, field, zsh, variable-assignment, parameter-expansion

It seems that when used in assignments, splitting with `${(f)...}` does only work when using `${var=...}` (in which case the result is joined again using the first character of $IFS), but not with regular assignments:

```
% zsh -c 'IFS=:$IFS; printf "> %s\n" ${s=${(f)"$(echo one; echo two)"}}; print ${(t)s}'  
> one:two
scalar
% zsh -c 'IFS=:$IFS; s=${(f)"$(echo one; echo two)"}; printf "> %s\n" $s; print ${(t)s}' 
> one
two
scalar
```

Is this documented behavior and what are the rules?